# Help with symbol writing

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I found this symbol in a document (written with Latex) and I wish to know how to write it myself:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try $\Im$ (symbol for imaginary axis).

Comment: Omg, I didn't realize it was so simple! Ty very much, @Zarko!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Lets you search for laTex symbols: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html